# How can I prove $\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{m , n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty} a_{m , n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

$\{a_{m , n}\}$  is a double sequence of real numbers with the following property.

For every $\epsilon$  we will get a natural number $k$ such that $|a_{m , n} - a_{p , q}| < \epsilon$  for all natural numbers $m , n , p , q > k$.

How can I prove that $$\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{m , n}  ,\quad  \lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty} a_{m , n} $$   exist, and $$\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{m , n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty} a_{m , n}?$$

Can anyone please help me? I think I can show the second part once I am able to prove the first part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given condition does *not* imply the existence of the horizontal and vertical limits. Example:
$$
a_{m,n} = \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{\min(m,n)} \, .
$$
For $m , n , p , q > k$ with $k >2/\epsilon$ is
$$
 |a_{m , n} - a_{p , q}| \le |a_{m , n}| + |a_{p , q}| \le \frac 1k + \frac 1k < \epsilon \, ,
$$
but $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_{m , n}$ does not exist for any $n$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{m , n}$ does not exist for any $m$.

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & \cdots \\
-1 & \frac 12 & -\frac 12 & \frac 12 & -\frac 12 & \frac 12 & \cdots \\
1 & -\frac 12 & \frac 13 & -\frac 13 & \frac 13 & -\frac 13 & \cdots \\
-1& \frac 12 & -\frac 13 & \frac 14 & -\frac 14 & \frac 14 & \cdots \\
1& -\frac 12 & \frac 13 & -\frac 14 & \frac 15 & -\frac 15 & \cdots \\
-1& \frac 12 & -\frac 13 & \frac 14 & -\frac 15 & \frac 16 & \cdots \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}
$$

However, *if* the horizontal and vertical limits
$$
 b_n = \lim_{m \to \infty} a_{m , n} \\
 c_m = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{m , n}
$$
exist for all $m$ respectively $n$, then the iterated limits $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ and $\lim_{m \to \infty} c_m$ exist as well, and they are equal.

Comment: Are you sûre it doesnt ? It seems like vertical and horizontal limit goes to zero. Indeed, when one variable goes to infinity, so does the maximum $\max \{m, n\}$

Comment: @AndreaMarino: Sorry, it should be the minimum, not the maximum.

Comment: @MartinR it's early on the east coast so my brain isn't fully on yet, but what's wrong with the thought of setting $q=n$? This would give $|a_{m, n} - a_{p, n}| <\varepsilon $. I'm missing something obvious I'm sure.

Comment: Ah is it because the limits are not decoupled but rather this is still looking at a sort of joint condition on the first and second index (like looking at the bottom right block if the sequence was viewed as an array)? Whereas the separated limits that OP is asking for should be independent of each other?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: That estimate holds only if $m,n,p$ are all $> k$. Therefore it does not work to prove that $a_{m,n}$ with a *fixed* $n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Yep just pieced that together myself. Man double sequences are funny things haha.